# jsf 2.0 spring stored procedure

Tags: mysql, spring, stored-procedures, jsf-2

Hello friends I am getting problem when injecting JSF bean into a bean that extends StoredProcedure abstract class...
The Bean return null values...

Comment: I'm no Spring expert, but it makes much more sense to me if you inject it the other way round. I.e. inject Spring bean in JSF bean and let JSF action method access/execute it.